# Combining Classification and Regression in a sequential way using MLP

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am looking for a way to do classification and regression sequentially?

For example, assuming samples have 3 input values and 1 output value. The model should first classify using the 3 input values and sequentially do the regression task using the classification output (i.e. classification has 3 input values from the original samples and regression has 4 input values (3 from the original samples + the classification output).

Below the architecture that I draw. However, not really sure about the part where the second input layer occurs. Could someone give advice or working examples for this application?

```
input1_classification = Input(shape=(3,))
hidden1 = Dense(20, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'(input1_classification)
# classsfication 
outputout_classification = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(hidden1)
# regression input 
input1_regression =Input(shape=(5,))
hidden2 = Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'(out_classification)
out_reg_final = Dense(1)(hidden2)
# define model
model = Model(inputs=input1_classification, outputs=[out_classification, out_reg_final])
# compile the keras modelmodel.compile(loss['sparse_categorical_crossentropy','mse'], optimizer='adam')

# fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(X_train, [y_train_class,y_train_reg], epochs=150, batch_size=32, verbose=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to concatenate your original input with the output of classification and apply your regression model there, you do not specify "extra" inputs.

So it will become something among the lines of:

```
input1_classification = Input(shape=(3,))

# classsfication 
hidden1 = Dense(20, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'(input1_classification)
outputout_classification = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(hidden1)

# regression input 
new_input = Concatenate(axis=1)([input1_classification, outputout_classification ])
hidden2 = Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'(new_input)
out_reg_final = Dense(1)(hidden2)

# define model
model = Model(inputs=input1_classification, outputs=[out_classification, out_reg_final])
# compile the keras modelmodel.compile(loss['sparse_categorical_crossentropy','mse'], optimizer='adam')

# fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(X_train, [y_train_class,y_train_reg], epochs=150, batch_size=32, verbose=2)
```